# Spring Batch Integration : SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter persisting the files from FTP server but not being processed by Joblauncher

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, sftp, inbound

I have a configuration class which is continuously polling my FTP directory. The weird behavior is SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter persists the file immediately in metadata store table but is not being picked up for processing by job launcher instantly. i have to manually delete that entry from metadata store table 3-4 times and then file is being picked up. is it code issue or FTP server issue? cant figure it out..

**Any idea if i am missing anything?**

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundNocFlow(FileNocMessageToJobRequest fileNocMessageToJobRequest) throws Exception {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(s -> s.sftp(this.sftpConfig.sftpSessionFactory())
                            .filter(this.sftpPersistantNocFilter())
                            .preserveTimestamp(true)
                            .remoteDirectory(this.sftpProperties.getRemoteOutboundDirectoryNoc())
                            .deleteRemoteFiles(this.sftpProperties.isDeleteRemoteFilesEnabled())
                            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                            .localDirectory(new File(FileUtils.getTempDirectoryPath() + this.sftpProperties.getLocalInboundDirectoryNoc())),
                            e -> e.id("sftpInboundNocAdapter")
                            .autoStartup(true)
                            .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(9000)))
            .handle(fileNocMessageToJobRequest)
            .handle(this.jobNocLaunchingGateway())
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.WARN, ">>>>>>>>>>headers.id + ': ' + payload")
            .channel("nullChannel")
            .get();
}



@Bean
public CompositeFileListFilter sftpPersistantNocFilter() {
    log.info("sftpPersistantNocFilter is called");
    CompositeFileListFilter nocfilters = new CompositeFileListFilter();
    nocfilters.addFilter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(this.metadataStore(),"Downloaded_File:"));
    nocfilters.addFilter(new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(".*\\bNOC\\b.*"));
   // nocfilters.addFilter(new SftpSimplePatternFileListFilter("*.csv"));
    return nocfilters;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently files are stored already on local directory and in the in-memory metadata store for those local files. You should consider to change a `local-filter`:

> You can use the local-filter attribute to configure the behavior of the local file system filter. Starting with version 4.3.8, a FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter is configured by default. This filter stores the accepted file names and modified timestamp in an instance of the MetadataStore strategy (see Metadata Store) and detects changes to the local file modified time. The default MetadataStore is a SimpleMetadataStore that stores state in memory.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp

Comment: Actually i have 5 inbound jobs running in parallel and polling the same directory looking for different files for which i have provided the filters. I think filters are working correctly, one of the file by one job is picked all the time, but other files are not being picked up by the job all the time. Is it any value which is being passed same for all other jobs like channel or any header id or timestamp?

Comment: to answer to your comment, files are not in local directory already. my job is not picking up the file for transferring to a local directory.

Comment: so the first job runs sucessfully picks the file and processes it, second job too runs in parallel, stores the other file in metadata store but second file is not being transfered to local directory. is this due to single thread executor mechanism?

Comment: You need to consider to use a `ChainFileListFilter` instead of that `CompositeFileListFilter` and reorder target filters: make an `SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter` as the first one. Otherwise all the files are placed into the `SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` first and isn't alligable for processing any more.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i resolved this issue by adding a separate bean name to filter in all the jobs and it worked.

Comment: Although i have another issue now, i have to delete the files from local directory after the processing is complete. But the files are not being deleted. I have tried few things to delete the file but nothing works:1. tried to delete the file in tasklet 2. tried to move the file to another directory 3. tried to delete the file in the afterJob() in jobExecution listener , it says file is being used by some another process. I read it that flatfileItemReader auto closes the file after reading,how to determine which process is using the file? Could you please suggest anything?

Comment: What does your `fileNocMessageToJobRequest` do? Does it close the file after using?

Comment: `@Transformer
    public JobLaunchRequest transform(File file) {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString(this.fileToParameterName, file.getAbsolutePath())
                .toJobParameters();

        return new JobLaunchRequest(this.job, jobParameters);
    }`

Comment: Yeah... Then it is indeed somewhere in Spring Batch or some other item reader or writer...

Comment: but reader and writer auto closes the streams, still i tried to reader.close before return reader; it dint worked.

Comment: My issue is resolved, file was used in BufferedReader which i am using to read the csv file, i closed that reader and it is deleted in tasklet. Thank you so much for help @ArtemBilan